# How to join surfaces together to form a 3D image in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, visualization, scientific-computing

I wish to achieve something very similar to this question: [How to join these two 3D lines together with a surface in Python's matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513262/how-to-join-these-two-3d-lines-together-with-a-surface-in-pythons-matplotlib)

There is an answer towards the bottom which is exactly the picture I would like to obtain, however, the surfaces I am dealing with are arbitrary and as a result I am unable to parametrize them. I have multiple 2D curves (each at a specific z level) and I wish to "connect" these, in part so it is visually obvious when the "width" of one closed surface is increasing as z increases.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is want you want but if you want to project two 2d-profiles of the 3d-surface you can use `offset=z` in the contour plot, where `z` is where in the z-axes you want to plot the profiles. Here is an example: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d_3.html

Comment: Thank you but this is a little different than what I am looking for

Comment: How are the data of you surface? X and Y are 1d arrays and Z a 2d array? You can try to filter X and Y for the desired value of Z

Comment: They are polygons that I obtained from taking the convex hull of some data points